# Null deviance vs deviance of null model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, deviance

In GLM analysis, is the null deviance of a model the same thing as the deviance of a null model?

Comment: In what context are you reading this? Many terms in math have multiple meanings, and many concepts go by multiple names, so much of the terminology comes down to author preference.

Comment: In R, why is the null deviance of a model `mod<-glm(y~x1+x2+x3)` , is not the same as the deviance of a null model `mod2<-glm(y~1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim *"In R, why is the null deviance of a model `mod<-glm(y~x1+x2+x3)` , is not the same as the deviance of a null model `mod2<-glm(y~1)`"* seems not true.  See the example below:

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
glm.Null <- glm(counts ~ 1, family = poisson())
# Return the null deviance of glm.D93
glm.D93$null.deviance # This is 10.58145
# Return the deviance of glm.Null
glm.Null$deviance     # This equals to 10.58145 too
```

As you may already know, the *deviance* of a GLM model $M$ is defined as (up to a scaling constant) the difference in twice the log-likelihood between $M$ and the saturated model $S$ (cf. *Categorical Data Analysis* (2nd edition), pp. 139 - 140; *Modern Applied Statistics with S* (4th edition), pp. 186 - 187).  The null deviance is the deviance when $M$ is taken to be the null model (i.e., the model with intercept only), which doesn't depend on the model specification.  Therefore, by definition, the "null deviance of a (specific) model" and the "deviance of a null model" should be identical.  If you found any counterexample, please elaborate by pasting out your code and outputs.